# Deploying simple Ruby code with Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have a simple Ruby application that works fine inside of the Heroku console (`heroku run ruby myapp.rb`). How can I have it running fully autonomously?

It's not a web based application, it basically reads some information from a website and sends out an email.

I created a Procfile

```
worker: ruby myapp.rb
```

Log says "config.ru not found", what should I put in my config.ru?

**Update**
Still not working...

Procfile:

```
worker: bundle exec ruby parse_reg.rb
```

config.ru:

```
require './parse_reg'
```

Heroku log:

> 2014-09-17T03:27:39+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation
>   started 2014-09-17T03:27:47+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug
>   compilation finished 2014-09-17T03:27:47.743136+00:00 heroku[api]:
>   Release v16 created by xyz@xyz.com
>   2014-09-17T03:27:47.743136+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d4e3e5f by
>   xyz@xyz.com 2014-09-17T03:27:48.989789+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   State changed from crashed to starting
>   2014-09-17T03:27:50.837609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 44532`
>   2014-09-17T03:28:51.121035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot
>   timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of
>   launch 2014-09-17T03:28:51.121241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping
>   process with SIGKILL

seems like my Procfile is not being read??? this is really strange!

Comment: Why are you running this on a webserver if it is not a "web application"?

Comment: It is not a webpage, but it does stuff like sending email and reading websites. Can you suggest a more suitable place for this type of application?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a config.ru in your project root and add

```
require './myapp'
```

Making sure that the myapp.rb file is a script that will run by just requiring it, which it looks like since it works by calling `ruby myapp.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured out the issue

I had to run the following to start the worker job

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku